# Make text invisible if there's no space left to fully display it

Tags: css, overflow

I'm developing a website and there is a place that has quotes in it I want it that if the text can't be displayed fully (basically if some words well get out off the div) I wan't the whole div to be invisible because I don't want some words to be cut off and I don't want to use things like `overflow: scroll;` so any ideas how can I fix this :)

Comment: I searched on Google and YouTube but I didn't find anything :(

Comment: you can use javascript for this thing (if you want), or you want only css

Comment: Not possible with CSS as overflow cannot be detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollWidth` is the width of elements with also not showable content.

and `offsetWidth` is the only showable content width.

---

so if the `scrollWidth` is different than `offsetWidth`, this means that is overflowing!

```js
if (divQuote.scrollWidth > divQuote.offsetWidth) {
      // put a display none on divQuote (css)
      // or use your logic to go to the next quote
}
```

> **useful docs:** 
>  scrollWidth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth 
>  offsetWidth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth

[image]

Comment: Tysm <3 This helped so much I added the same things for height like offsetHeight and it worked the only problem is that if I resize the window so that it has enough space it still won't show even though the function is calling itself every half a second, I will let you know if I find a solution to it tho

Comment: @D4rKen no, use a `eventListener`, is more efficient https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: Oh I didn't know that a resize listener exist in event listeners thank you so much :)